# Check for user in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code, which checks the address bar for the string `?user=`:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("?user=") > -1) {
    start();
} else {
    alert("No user.");
}
```

But actually I would like to check, if the `?user=` has something after it, for example a name. I would be glad if you could help me out.

Comment: You could do that (see [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)). However, that smells like you're implementing a very bad security system...

Comment: In this case security doesn't matter, however thanks for the tip.

Comment: `/\?user\=./.test(window.location.search)` checks if any character comes after the equal sign ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression match.

```
if(window.location.href.match(/\?user=[^&]/) {
    start();
} else {
    alert("No user.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use this regular expression:

```
/user=\w+(&|$)/.test(window.location.search)
```

Comment: It's not necessary to check for both `\w` and `\d`, since digits are included in `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = (window.location.search.match(/user=(\w+)/) || [])[1];

if(user) {
    start();
} else {
    alert('No user.');
}
```